# The collision of two balls

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

At $t=0$ let's consider two particles with mass $m_1$ and $m_2$ respectively travelling on a smooth surface in same direction ($m_2$ is in front of $m_1$ )  with initial velocity $v_{o1}$ and  $v_{o2}$, where $v_{o1}\gt v_{o2}$. They are acted by the force of universal gravitation which cause $m_1$ to accelerate and $m_2$ to decelerate. Collision occurs at $t=t_o$, where they have velocity $v_{i1}$ and $v_{i2}$ ($v_{i1} \gt v_{i2}$). After the collision ($t=t_o+\delta t$) they have velocity $v_{f1}$ and $v_{f2}$ ($v_{f1} \lt v_{f2}$).
$$ W_{universal-gravitation}=\frac{1}{2}\mu[(v_{i1}-v_{i2})^2 -(v_{o1}-v_{o2})^2] = \Delta E_{k(0 \to t_o)}$$
$$W_{Collision- Force}=\frac{1}{2}\mu[(v_{f2}-v_{f1})^2 -(v_{i1}-v_{i2})^2]= \Delta E_{k(t_o\to t_o+\delta t)}$$
$*\mu $ is reduced mass of two particles*

According to my textbook collision is a process that takes infinitesimal short time and the displacements of particles involved are infinitesimal small in the process, so that we can ignore non- collision force (external force).

So the conclusion is that universal gravitational force did work only on $(t=0 ~~\to~~ t=t_o)$, and at $(t=t_o~~\to~~ t=t_o+\delta t)$, the collision force is so large that work done by universal gravitational force is negligible. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an elastic collision in mid-air, then it is customary to assume that the potential energy does not change during the short time associated with the collision.  If you assume the objects are sliding on a smooth horizontal surface, then the force of gravity would be met by a normal force from the surface.

Comment: I’m considering the universal gravitational force between those balls instead of gravity.

Comment: Gravity by any name acts for a very short time during a collision.

Comment: so we can neglect it？

Comment: Only till after the collision.